# Mongo shell - TypeError - not a function

Tags: mongodb, shell, drop

So I'm trying to tidy up my database.

I logged into shell, made a `show collections` request and then I wanted to delete some of those.

I used `db.collection_name.drop()` and it helped for a while. A dozen of collections were deleted successfully.
But then I got to a collection called "stats".

`db.stats.drop()` brings error `E QUERY [js] TypeError: db.stats.drop is not a function : @(shell):1:1`

The only difference with previous successful drops is the collection name.
So I'm guessing maybe it's a reserved word or something? How do I drop it? I thought shell is the best way to do such things.

Comment: try `getCollection`.  `db.stats()` is a function.

Comment: Thanks! db.getCollection("stats").drop() worked!

Answer (score 2):

`db.getCollection("stats").drop()` did the job